# Github + Mediatemple or Beanstalk? How should I be using Github?

Tags: git, deployment, github, workflow

I've been doing a lot of research on getting set up with Git and coming up with a good strategy for deployment.  (For background, I have formerly been on GoDaddy and FTP.  Yuck.)

Several successful developers have told me my Github account can be a very powerful developer resume, and that I should put my own site on there, as well as work on contributing to open source projects.  So I would like certain repos of mine to be available there.

The options I've come down to for my set up are either:

A) Use Beanstalk to both host my clients' sites and store all of my repos.  Somehow also push certain repos to Github, and use this only for my site, open source stuff, etc.  (not sure how to do that part)

B) Use Github to store both private and public repos, and host with a company like MediaTemple that allows SSH access and Git (unlike GoDaddy).

It seems like the Beanstalk approach is simplest and has really good documentation.  Are there any drawbacks to doing things this way?  How should Github be incorporated in the workflow?  Is anyone using both of these together?

Comment: Wait, are you talking about [Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/elasticbeanstalk/) or [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/)? Yay for trademark infringement.

Comment: Talking about the latter Beanstalk.  Although now it looks like I misunderstood a bit and Beanstalk doesn't offer actual web hosting, but just a place to store repos (with a deployment option).  I get that now, but still unclear whether to use Github or Beanstalk, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm exploring these options myself and looking for a new workflow. I'm still figuring it out.

I have a GS Account with Media Temple and what I like about it is the privacy. The [MT knowledge base has a good article](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1594/Using+Git#gs) on how to set it up. You'll end up with a subdomain that you can use as a Git repo. The deployment is something you would have to do on your own I guess through the Terminal or FTP.  Maybe Git-Tower has deployment feature. I know from watching a video on CSS Tricks that Beanstalk as a Deployment feature and it's private, where GitHub is public/social as free service, but you can pay and get a private setup.

Check out these videos (I didn't feel so clueless after I watch Chris punch his way through too)

[#101: Let's Suck at GitHub Together](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/101-lets-suck-at-github-together/)

[#109: Getting off FTP and onto Git Deployment with Beanstalk GIT](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/109-getting-off-ftp-and-onto-git-deployment-with-beanstalk/)

Here's some of what I remember (some of it you already know as you detailed in your question).
GitHub: social, public, collaborative, free (no deployment)
Beanstalk: private, sharable-collaborative, paid (with option for deployment)
Media Temple: private, paid if your already hosting - pretty nice for a subdomain repo.

I'm less afraid of the terminal than I used to be and I've been using Cornerstone/SVN as my current local dev-version workflow, but [Git-Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) looks pretty nice too and kind of like Cornerstone. I'm not sure maybe Tower has a deployment option.

Answer (score -1):

Elastic Beanstalk is a PaaS framework for building durable, autoscaling applications on AWS.  It is completely the wrong choice for your proposed usage scenario.  It will be needlessly complex and expensive.  You're much better off using a VPS (or even a shared hosting account).

Comment: Pretty sure he means this [beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) and the question is just mis-tagged...

Comment: Christopher is right - didn't realize there was something else called Beanstalk.  I'm talking about the Beanstalk app here: http://beanstalkapp.com/